# Draw lines without the -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview

I want to make a chart inside an UIView. Something like this: 
[image]

Is there an easier way to draw the lines than using this method:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f); //start at this point

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20.0f, 20.0f); //draw to this point

    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

?

Comment: Try `PCLineChartView` [link](https://github.com/honcheng/iOSPlot/tree/master/iOSPlot), an easy way to draw chart like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `UIBezierPath` class:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:startPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:endPoint];
[path stroke];
```

If you need to draw a chart, try to use [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) - plotting framework.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `UIBezierPath` a high-level implementation from Apple.

Simply refer [UIBezierPath - Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276) for more info